# Can the first player choose where to put cards down?

Tags: kanagawa

The rulebook seems unclear to me, as to whether they must be placed left-to-right, or if the first player gets to choose what columns they go into.

https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/7d/9c/d0-kanagawa-rulebook.pdf

Answer (score 1):

They are placed left-to-right.

Although you are correct that the rulebook is not completely explicit on this point, the example given on page 8 provides the answer.

> In a 4-player game, draw 4 Lesson cards and place them on the first row of the board as follows: the first and second cards face-up, the third card face-down, and the last card face-up.

The key is that the third card is the one that is placed face-down, as shown in the third space on the play mat. If you could choose the order, it wouldn’t always be the third card that went face-down.

Comment: I’m inclined to believe you, but could also interpret these “first” and “last” namings as indices of position only, not indices of both time and position.